# Changed the path to wp-login and now can't access WPress dashboard

Tags: wp-admin, login

I'm in desperate need of help.  In Wordpress under settings, I removed the sub-directory and saved.  Now I can't get back to Wordpress or my login page which was http://www.deccan.co.nz/WP/wp-admin/.  I've tried to amend the wp-login.php page with the below code, but this doesn't work.

```
if ( $url != get_option( 'siteurl' ) )
    require( dirname(__WP__) . '/wp-load.php' );    

update_option('siteurl', 'http://www.deccan.co.nz/WP/' );
update_option('home', 'http://www.deccan.co.nz/WP/' )
```

Any other ideas?
Thanks in desperation
Felicia

Answer (score 0):

Perform below steps -

1. Go to PHP My Admin.
2. In your site database find table "wp_options".
3. Find "siteurl" under "option_name" column.
4. Change the "siteurl" **option_value** from "http://www.deccan.co.nz/" to "**http://www.deccan.co.nz/WP/**" and you are done.